# How to format a number 0..9 to display with 2 digits (it's NOT a date)

Tags: java, number-formatting

I'd like to always show a number under 100 with 2 digits (example: 03, 05, 15...)

How can I append the 0 without using a conditional to check if it's under 10?

I need to append the result to another String, so I cannot use printf.

Answer (score 674, accepted):

You can use:

```
String.format("%02d", myNumber)
```

See also the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

Comment: What if myNumber is a double?

Comment: @Fra, then you would use `String.format("%02.0f", myNumber)` if you don't want the numbers after the decimal point

Comment: For those who want to read specifically about the string format syntax: 
[Format String Syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

Comment: This will generate an Android Linter Warning 
"Implicitly using the default locale is a common source of bugs: Use String.format(Locale, ...) instead"

Comment: @ChristopherStock That's a completely separate issue, to do with using the correct default locale of the device the app is running on - you can ignore or fix it, but that's related to Android and locales only. Nothing to do with the actual string formatting

Comment: If, like me, this answer didnt help you and you feel frustrated, please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/29882814/11561121

Answer (score 76):

If you need to print the number you can use printf

```
System.out.printf("%02d", num);
```

You can use

```
String.format("%02d", num);
```

or

```
(num < 10 ? "0" : "") + num;
```

or

```
(""+(100+num)).substring(1);
```

Comment: Using a format is by far the slowest, but it is clearer and less unlikely to go horribly wrong. e.g. if num is -1. ;)

Answer (score 64):

You can use this:

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("00");  
String s = formatter.format(1); // ----> 01
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! The result of the solution via String.format may vary due to locale settings. (s. Android Linter Warning "Implicitly using the default locale is a common source of bugs: Use String.format(Locale, ...) )

Comment: Thanks. This also works with negatives: -2 --> -02

Answer (score 6):

The String class comes with the format abilities:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%02d", 5));
```

for full documentation, here is the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

Comment: It says `java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: %d can't format java.lang.Double arguments`

Answer (score 4):

In android resources it's rather simple

```
<string name="smth">%1$02d</string>
```

Answer (score 2):

I know that is late to respond, but there are a basic way to do it, with no libraries. If your number is less than 100, then:

`(number/100).toFixed(2).toString().slice(2);`

Comment: Genial solution but hardly readable for future coworkers

Comment: Uy! I made a mistake, this code is js, and the post is about java.

Answer (score 1):

in less code:

```
print(f"{2:02} {4:03}")
```