# How to write integer with two digits?

Tags: java, integer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to format a number 0..9 to display with 2 digits (it’s NOT a date)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421444/how-to-format-a-number-0-9-to-display-with-2-digits-its-not-a-date)

How can I write an integer number with two digits in Java? For example if the integer is less than 10, the program should return `01` to `09`. I need that `0` in front of the one digit number. Something like `%.2f`  for double type.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Assuming that, since you know about `%.2f` for formatting `double`, so you at least know about `formatting`.

So, to format your integers appropriately, you can prepend a `0` before `%2d` to pad your numbers with `0` at the beginning: -

```
int i = 9;
System.out.format("%02d\n", i);  // Will print 09
```

Answer (score 18):

Use **String.format** method...

Example

```
  System.out.println(String.format("%02d", 5));
  System.out.println(String.format("%02d", 55));
  System.out.println(String.format("%02d", 15));
```

Answer (score 1):

"Write" how? Assuming you mean from a `PrintStream`, you can use [`printf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) for that. Formatting details [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax). I believe the format string would be `%02d`.