# Overloaded method call has alternatives: String.format

Tags: string, scala, unicode, stringbuilder

I wrote the following Scala code below to handle a String that I pass in, format the String, append it to a `StringBuilder` and return the formatted `String` with escaped unicode back to my caller for other processing.

The Scala compiler complains of the following on the lines where there is a `String.format` call with the following error:

> overloaded method value format with alternatives: `(x$1; java.util.Locale; x$2: String, X$3: Object*)`  `(x$1:String,x$2: Object*)` String cannot be applied to `(*String, Int)`

```
class TestClass {    
    private def escapeUnicodeStuff(input: String): String = {
            //type StringBuilder = scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder
            val sb = new StringBuilder()
            val cPtArray = toCodePointArray(input) //this method call returns an Array[Int]
            val len = cPtArray.length
            for (i <- 0 until len) {
              if (cPtArray(i) > 65535) {
                val hi = (cPtArray(i) - 0x10000) / 0x400 + 0xD800
                val lo = (cPtArray(i) - 0x10000) % 0x400 + 0xDC00
                sb.append(String.format("\\u%04x\\u%04x", hi, lo)) //**complains here**
              } else if (codePointArray(i) > 127) {
                sb.append(String.format("\\u%04x", codePointArray(i))) //**complains here**
              } else {
                sb.append(String.format("%c", codePointArray(i))) //**complains here**
              }
            }
            sb.toString
          }

    }
```

---

How do I address this problem? How can I clean up the code to accomplish my purpose of formatting a String? Thanks in advance to the Scala experts here

Comment: Thanks once again for the edits. The question looks so much more nicer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) method in Java expects `Objects` as its arguments.  The `Object` type in Java is equivalent to the `AnyRef` type in Scala.  The primitive types in Scala extend `AnyVal` – not `AnyRef`.  Read more about the differences between `AnyVal`, `AnyRef`, and `Any` [in the docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/128) or in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335319/what-are-the-relationships-between-any-anyval-anyref-object-and-how-do-they-m).  The most obvious fix is to use the `Integer` wrapper class from Java to get an `Object` representation of your `Ints`:

```
String.format("\\u%04x\\u%04x", new Integer(hi), new Integer(lo))
```

Using those wrapper classes is almost emblematic of unidiomatic Scala code, and should only be used for interoperability with Java when there is no better option.  The more natural way to do this in Scala would be to either use the [`StringOps`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.StringOps) equivalent method `format`:

```
"\\u%04x\\u%04x".format(hi, lo)
```

You can also use the [`f` interpolator](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html#the-f-interpolator) for a more concise syntax:

```
f"\\u$hi%04x\\u$lo%04x"
```

Also, using a `for` loop like you have here is unidiomatic in Scala.  You're better off using one of the functional list methods like `map`, `foldLeft`, or even `foreach` together with a partial function using the `match` syntax.  For example, you might try something like:

```
toCodePointArray(input).foreach {
    case x if x > 65535 => 
        val hi = (x - 0x10000) / 0x400 + 0xD800
        val lo = (x - 0x10000) % 0x400 + 0xDC00
        sb.append(f"\\u$hi%04x\\u$lo%04x") 
    case x if > 127 => sb.append(f"\\u$x%04x") 
    case x => sb.append(f"$x%c")    
}
```

Or, if you don't have to use `StringBuilder`, which really only needs to be used in cases where you are appending many strings, you can replace your whole method body with `foldLeft`:

```
def escapeUnicodeStuff(input: String) = toCodePointArray(input).foldLeft("") {
    case (acc, x) if x > 65535 => 
        val hi = (x - 0x10000) / 0x400 + 0xD800
        val lo = (x - 0x10000) % 0x400 + 0xDC00
        acc + f"\\u$hi%04x\\u$lo%04x"
    case (acc, x) if x > 127 => acc + f"\\u$x%04x"
    case (acc, x) => acc + f"$x%c"
}
```

Or a even `map` followed by a `mkString`:

```
def escapeUnicodeStuff(input: String) = toCodePointArray(input).map {
    case x if x > 65535 => 
        val hi = (x - 0x10000) / 0x400 + 0xD800
        val lo = (x - 0x10000) % 0x400 + 0xDC00
        f"\\u$hi%04x\\u$lo%04x"
    case x if x > 127 => f"\\u$x%04x"
    case x => f"$x%c"
}.mkString
```

Comment: Thanks for taking so much time and effort in answering. I liked your explanation very lucid and informative.  I like the case approach quite elegant.

Comment: With the second solution the compiler says: type mismatch: Unit required: String

Comment: I got it right. Your code was just perfect. I just was'nt seeing things right. Thanks

Comment: you are a real life saver

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't figure out what exactly is causing that "overload clash" but notice the code below:

```
scala> "\\u%04x\\u%04x".format(10,20)
res12: String = \u000a\u0014
```

Using the one provided by [StringOps](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.immutable.StringOps) works.

Comment: Do you mean the method provided by StringOps?